# Vba or Formula to allocate amount based on dates

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

is it possible to allocate (split) amount based on dates?
For example, I have this situation:

```
ID           Date    Invoice value  ColumnD
ID0001    01/01/2020    200         here I need to insert the value
ID0001    01/02/2020    300         here I need to insert the value
ID0001    01/03/2020    500         here I need to insert the value
ID0002    01/03/2020    1000        here I need to insert the value
ID0002    01/04/2020    1500        here I need to insert the value
```

I know that the value to allocate, for ID0001 is 600 and for ID0002 is 2000.
Now I need to allocate the first 100 based on dates on ID0001. So I could have:

```
ID           Date    Invoice value  ColumnD
ID0001    01/01/2020    200         0
ID0001    01/02/2020    300         0
ID0001    01/03/2020    500         400
ID0002    01/03/2020    1000        here I need to insert the value
ID0002    01/04/2020    1500        here I need to insert the value
```

And the second one value (200) allocate in this way:

```
ID           Date    Invoice value  ColumnD
ID0001    01/01/2020    200         0
ID0001    01/02/2020    300         0
ID0001    01/03/2020    500         400
ID0002    01/03/2020    1000        0
ID0002    01/04/2020    1500        500
```

Is it possible to do this with formula or VBA?

Comment: Andrea, are you storing your payments in the workbook or do you wish to just enter them and have the balances adjusted?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some VBA to get you started. It does some of the error checking but not all. The biggest hole is what to do if a payment exceeds the total amount of invoices outstanding.
Note: I created a range name for testing "InvoiceIDs" you'll want to make this a dynamic range name so you don't have to worry about it in the future. The macro also assumes that the invoice numbers will always be in sorted order!

```
Option Explicit

Sub PostInvoice()

   Dim zId  As Variant
   Dim dPmt As Variant
   Dim lRow As Long
   Dim rng  As Range
   
   lRow = 0
   
   Do While lRow = 0
   
     zId = InputBox("Enter Account ID", "Account Selection:")
     If (zId = "") Then Exit Sub
    
     On Error Resume Next
       lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(zId, Range("InvoiceIDs"), 0)
       Set rng = Cells(lRow, 4)
     On Error GoTo 0
   
     If (lRow = 0) Then
       MsgBox "Invoice ID: " & zId & " Not Found!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
     End If
  
   Loop
   
   dPmt = InputBox("Enter Payment Amount", "Record a Payment:")
   If (dPmt = "") Then Exit Sub
   
     
   Do While dPmt > 0
     
     If (rng.Value > 0) Then
     
       If (dPmt >= rng.Value) Then
         dPmt = dPmt - rng.Value
         rng.Value = 0
       Else
         rng.Value = rng.Value - dPmt
         dPmt = 0
       End If
        
     End If
     
     Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
     
     If (rng.Offset(0, -3).Value <> zId) Then Exit Do
   
   Loop

End Sub 'PostInvoice
```

Other things to consider would be turning the InputBoxes into a UserForm for a smoother interface.

Before Run:

[image]

After Run:

[image]
HTH

Answer (score 0):

Let "Allocated value" put in Column D

Then, in E2, formula copied down :

```
=MAX(0,SUMIF(A$2:A2,A2,C$2:C2)-SUMIF(A:A,A2,D:D))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi All, Thanks, for your support.

Comment: Bosco_Yip, When i tried to use your formula I meet an error. I you consider the following data you will find an error on row number 4 and on row number 6. For this rows, the value in column is not correct. Can you help me? Many thanks, Andrea

Comment: Codice Pratica Data Fattura Importo Fattura Importo da Allocare Nuovo Residuo su Fattura
Z1634693 26/02/2008  963,40   1.000,00  0
Z1634693 30/03/2008  1.338,90   1302,3
Z1634693 23/04/2008  1.339,30   2641,6
Z1634694 10/05/2008  1.329,10   550,00  779,1
Z1634694 09/07/2008  64,90   844

Comment: Thanks All, i solved my problem with your support. Many thanks, Andrea